# Laravel - sendResetLink not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, forgot-password

Within my project, I have given the administrator role the privilege to add users to the site. For security reasons, I hash a random string, to store as the temporary password, I then want to send the user an email with the standard Laravel reset password template.

I have the following:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = Input::get('name');
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make(str_random(8));
$user->save();

$response = Password::sendResetLink(Input::get('email'), function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject('Password Reset');
    });
```

The error I'm getting is

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::sendResetLink() must be of
>   the type array, string given

How can I trigger this function within Laravel, so the user is sent a password reset email? Thank you.

Comment: I think the error is pretty self-explanatory. The `sendResetLink` expects an array and you're providing a string.

Comment: @PawelMysior, very true, that is the problem I am having. I'm unsure of what it wants within the Array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are sending string email, and you should send array (this is what error says).

You should in this case use:

```
Request::only('email')
```

instead of

```
Input::get('email')
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I tried this but the following error is returned `Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::only() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`.

Comment: @Ben So change `Request` here into `\Request` to use `Request` facade here.